# SQL Len(replace)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

In SQL Server 2005, I have a `timestamp` type column. I want to convert to the `datetime` type. For example:

```
'20170824112344'
```

But they can come bad. For example:

```
'____123456____'

_ = blank spaces
```

I want to filter by those with length 14.

```
case
   when len(replace(fecha,' ','')) = 14 
      then convert(smalldatetime, SUBSTRING(fecha, 7, 2) + '-' + 
                                  SUBSTRING(fecha, 5, 2) + '-' +  
                                  SUBSTRING(fecha, 1,4) + ' ' + 
                                  SUBSTRING(fecha, 9, 2) + ':' + 
                                  SUBSTRING(fecha, 11, 2) + ':00', 103)
      else fecha
end as fecha
```

but it does not work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could just check that the string consists entirely of 14 digits:

```
SELECT
    CONVERT(smalldatetime, SUBSTRING(fecha, 1, 4) + '-' + SUBSTRING(fecha, 5, 2)
         + '-' +  SUBSTRING(fecha, 7, 2) + ' ' + SUBSTRING(fecha, 9, 2) + ':' + 
         SUBSTRING(fecha, 11, 2) + ':00', 120) AS fecha
FROM yourTable
WHERE fecha
    LIKE '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'
```

Note that I removed the `CASE` expression because you can't return both a string and a datetime from the same expression.

## Demo

Comment: One can argue that `LTRIM` and `RTRIM` are not really necessary as `LIKE` ensures that the string is 14 characters long and is made up of numbers only.

Comment: But I need all the records.
If you can convert to date, but what you have

Comment: If my answer does not work for you then update your question showing clear input and the expected output.